# Which hadoop version should I choose among 1.x, 2.2 and 0.23

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

Hello I am new to Hadoop and pretty confused with the version names and which one should I use among 1.x ( great support and learning resources ), 2.2 or 0.23.

I have read that hadoop is moving to YARN completely from v0.23 ( [link1](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current2/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html) ). 
 But at the same time its all over the web that hadoop v2.0 is moving to YARN ( [link2](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop/yarn/) ) and I can see the YARN configuration files in Hadoop 2.2 itself.

- But since 0.23 seems to be the latest version to me, Does 2.2 also
  support YARN ? ( Refer link 1, it says hadoop will support YARN from
  v0.23 )
- And as a beginner which version should I go for 1.x or 2.x for
  learning perspective of hadoop.
- Are other technologies that works with hadoop like pig, hive etc.
  available with the latest version of hadoop?

Thanks.

**UPDATE** 
Thankyou all for replying.
I ended up using hadoop2.2 and since all famous tutorials and resources are outdated, though I found one good book to get started with v2.2.

> "Hadoop: The Definitive Guide, Third Edition" by Tom White ([Buy Here](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021773.do))

supports hadoop v2.2.

The **source code** is give on github  https://github.com/tomwhite/hadoop-book

as mentioned on github, the code of the book is tested with

```
This version of the code has been tested with:
 * Hadoop 1.2.1/0.22.0/0.23.x/2.2.0
 * Avro 1.5.4
 * Pig 0.9.1
 * Hive 0.8.0
 * HBase 0.90.4/0.94.15
 * ZooKeeper 3.4.2
 * Sqoop 1.4.0-incubating
 * MRUnit 0.8.0-incubating
```

hope it helps..!!!

Comment: The link to the book is broken. I found this commercial one: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021773.do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few active release series. The 1.x release series is a continuation of the 0.20
release series. A few weeks after 0.23 released, the 0.20 branch formerly known as 0.20.205 was renumbered 1.0.  There is next to no functional difference between 0.20.205 and 1.0.  This is just a renumbering.

The 0.23 includes several major new features includes a new MapReduce runtime, called MapReduce 2, implemented on a new system called YARN (Yet Another Resource Negotiator), which is a general resource management system for running distributed applications. Similarly, 2.x release is a continuation of the 0.23 release series. So the 2.2 also support YARN.

According to [Hadoop 2.2 release note](http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html#Download)

- 1.2.X - current stable version, 1.2 release
- 2.2.X - current stable 2.x version
- 0.23.X - similar to 2.X.X but missing NN HA.

I would suggest starting with [Cloudera](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/home.html) distribution since you just start learning. The CDH 4.5 includes the YARN feature you are looking for. You can also try [HortonWorks](http://hortonworks.com/) distribution. The advantage of going with these vendors is that you do not need to worry about which version of components such as Hive, Pig to work with your Hadoop installation.

Comment: Thank you so much. Won't there be any problem with limited learning resources on cloudera or hortonworks. I can find plenty of resources from ebooks to video tutorials on hadoop, pig etc. But I doubt that for the above 2 distributions.

Comment: That should not be a problem. All the learning resource about hadoop 2 you find online should apply to these distribution too.  You can also find distribution specific feature on their company web sites.

Answer (score 1):

I recommended  you to start with hadoop-2.2.0 which gives good knowledge. Industry prefers YARN itself and in production 2.x only exists

Comment: Will I face any problem in using hadoop-2.2.0 by using tutorials and guides from v1.x