# Hadoop Versions seem to fall under 0.x, 1.x, and 2.x, but when discussing YARN/MapReduce, every page Refers to Hadoop 1 and Hadoop 2.0

Tags: hadoop

On Apache's distribution page, Hadoop seems to exist in 0.x, 1.x, and 2.x. However, when discussing MapReduce/Yarn, and deciding on a version of Hive and Hbase, there only seems to be discussion of Hadoop 1 and 2. Why is this? Is 0.x just a beta release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1.X and 2.X versions derive from the 0.X line, which is still being continued (as far as I know). The version numbering is quite confusing. A helpful chart can be found at https://blogs.apache.org/bigtop/entry/all_you_wanted_to_know . Even if it's quite outdated, you can see the relevant branches and what derives from what.

Also check [Hadoop release version confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23787587/hadoop-release-version-confusing) for more explanation.